# Suddenly my server is down due to low resource

Tags: resources, limit

I have only 2 small websites. My server is down now due to low resource. and I did check my server, and more specifically its resource limits. The shell command is cat /proc/user_beancounters At the time of my check, othersockbuf limit has been hit 2994 times! Also, there were 94 active concurrent connections to your SMTP server

netstat -antpu | awk {'print $4'} | grep :25 |wc -l
94

The above makes me think my server either is experiencing lack of resources, either someone is trying to send you a hacker too much emails.

Any firgure out how to resolve it? I have a firewall installed but no configured it.

Answer (score 0):

You could install fail2ban and configure/activate a jail for services like mail, webserver and ssh.

Please post the full output of `cat /proc/user_beancounters` and of `cat /proc/net/sockstat` for more help.